# Azure notification hub

Tags: c#, ios, azure, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a project with azure notification hub using my student Microsoft account. I start Microsoft free account and create another hub and using the same APNS certification from the first project. Now I can receive notification when I send test message from azure portal but I can't receive any message when I send it from my app. Using the same app just change the connections string and hub name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using the same app just change the connections string and hub name?

Normally, we will not send the notification directly from the client app. We usually send the notification from the server backend. About how to send the notification from backend you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-push).

If you still want to send the notification by codes from your app, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started#sending-push-notifications).

In this article, provide three way to send the notification.

Using C# codes, node.js, rest api. You could choose one way to achieve your requirement.

Here is C# codes demo.

1.Install Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs from Nuget package.

2.Use below codes to send the notification.

```
 private static async void SendNotificationAsync()
 {
     NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("<connection string with full access>", "<hub name>");
     var alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Hello from .NET!\"}}";
     await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(alert);
 }
```

---

Update:

I suggest you could check your connection string make sure the connection has the permission to send the notification.

Like this:

[image]

Then you could add this connection to the codes and set the right notification hub name in it.

Comment: I have a backend in azure server and use it to send notification in my test account, but when I start my azure free account it's not work? in backend I have web app using C#, this code receive message from client app request and send it by using APNS.

Comment: Firstly, I suggest you could try to create a console application to run the C# codes to test you could send the notification with the right connection string. What do you mean of two account? In your test account you could send the notification, In the free account you couldn't?

Comment: Yes, I have a student account and real free account. In student account it's work but in real free account don't?

Comment: 1. I suggest you could check your free account has the enough $ to run the notification hub. The free account could start a notification hub. 2. I suggest you could check you have used connection string set in your application.

Comment: !. I have one month free trial with about 1600SEK. 2. I use SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey for connection string.

Comment: I suggest you could open the web portal to recheck you have copy the right connection string and  test again. More details, you could see me updated answer.

Comment: Yes I use the same connection string as you suggest?

Comment: How you set your client app to get the notification? Use the azure mobile app setting or implement it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Brando for suggestion. I found that some fail in Hub setting in backend.